# how to format the specified cell value in two different formats in SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, sqlreportingservice

I have SSRS report data where we will have two different thing in some of the cells, For example:
**Old Values in SourceDB**

```
FirstName   LastName 
Robin       Son
BOB         Alice
```

**Updating the DB values:**

```
FirstName   LastName 
Robin       S
BOB         A
```

After some update, we will have the changes and new & old values in Audit Table so the report will be created like this.

```
FirstName LastName
Robin     was: Son now: S
BOB       Was: Allice now: A
```

Is it possible to have the Was value in Red color and the now value in Green Color.
In worst case if it is not possible how to make the whole cell value into red.

Thanks for the suggestions or answers or even feedback's are appreciated.

Comment: Will your `Was:` and `Now:` be consistent in case etc within your `Audit` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change your `Audit` table per Ashiko's very sensible recommendation to hold the `Was` and `Now` values in seperate columns, you will need to parse out the relevant parts of your string value in your report.

One way you can do this is through `placeholder`s that have expression based values.  In your SSRS table, add 4 `placeholder`s to a table that is based on your `Audit` dataset, with the following expressions as their `Label` and `Value`:

1. `Was:` - `="Was: "`
2. `Old Value` - `=replace(left(Fields!LastName.Value,instr(Fields!LastName.Value," Now:")-1),"Was: ","")`
3. `Now:` - `="Now: "`
4. `New Value` - `=mid(Fields!LastName.Value,instrrev(Fields!LastName.Value,":")+2,99999)`

You can then format the individual `placeholder` items as you would normal text, with some one colour and others another.

If you do this correctly, you should end up with something like this:

Design View:
[image]

Rendered:
[image]

---

Do be aware though, that if you do resort to splitting your string values in this manner, if that pattern you are searching for (eg: `Now:` in the old value or `:` in your new value) you will get undesirable results in your report.

If this is an entirely internal report for monitoring purposes, this is probably not an issue.  If this will be customer facing however, I strongly recommend that you add additional columns to your `Audit` table for the `Old` and `New` value to allow you absolute control.

Comment: I already have separate column only in Audit Table but in Select query I am merging the result from Audit table and displaying it together in single cell in SSRS.

Comment: In that case, return the values as individual columns in your SSRS dataset and reference them in the 2nd and 4th `placeholder` expressions per my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

1. Select the cell
2. Click F4 to open cell properties or right click the properties
3. In font tab , Select Color

4 Select Underneath Expression

5 Write as

=iif(Fields!ColumnName.Value = "WAS","Red","Green")

Comment: but this will change the whole cell format, I am expecting that WAS: item to be formatted in that color.

Comment: you may create a column as identifier if its was or now then use it in the expression. separate the cell for the term WAS and NOW in the report and create new column for its value so it wont affect the whole cell.